# Fixed - Importing module from parent folder in child module - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following folder structure.

```
root
   .
   .
   B.py 
   test──
        ├
        A.py
```

I can import A.py in B.py by

```
from test import A
```

But, How to import B.py in A.py?

I tried the following code in A.py but it didn't work. I have referred to multiple links but didn't find an appropriate answer.

```
import os
import sys

scriptpath = "../"

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(scriptpath))
import B
```

It wasn't running from VSCode terminal, not sure why. But, It ran from command prompt. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tried running your code and it worked. Can you describe the error you got?

Comment: @KienNguyen No Module named B

Comment: @Venkat, for me, works as well. How do you execute A?

Comment: @EgorWexler I am using vscode, and I am running the code like this in test folder, python A.py

Comment: @Venkat, did you try to execute it simply from the command line without vscode?

Comment: @EgorWexler Thanks It worked from command prompt. Seems like VSCode terminal has some problem. Also please confirm is it the standard way of importing?

Comment: @Venkat, yes, it is. You can also refer here for relative imports: [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) in part 5.7